# Change computer name of an Ubuntu desktop computer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, computer-name

How can I change the computer name on an Ubuntu desktop computer?

I already tried changing the `/etc/hostname` file but that only caused the wireless to stop working.  I found an [old guide](http://linux.about.com/od/ubuntu_doc/a/ubudg26t2.htm) that suggested changing the setting under networking, but that screen doesn't exist in 9.10 (Karmic Koala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial on Ubuntu Forums: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=774029)

> This is a short and sweet howto that is nonetheless very important. It
>   is based on my experiences when changing the hostname of a system. The
>   hostname is effectively just the name of the system. You do not
>   usually need to change it, but if you do have to for whatever reason,
>   it isn't very difficult at all.
>
> Whilst changing the hostname is not a difficult task in itself, it can
>   be dangerous because if the system cannot resolve it's own hostname,
>   it is impossible to sudo. Thus, if done improperly, changing a
>   hostname can lock you out of your own system. Firstly, and most
>   importantly, we make backups. Go to accessories/terminal and paste
>   this command in, then press enter:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak && sudo cp /etc/hostname /etc/hostname.bak
> ```
>
> You MUST make backups, just in case. If you can't boot to a usable
>   system after finishing this howto, or sudo doesn't work, see the
>   instructions at the end of this guide. If you aren't completely
>   familiar with the linux terminal, it might be a good idea to write
>   these down or print them off.
>
> Ok, now we have made backups, we can edit /etc/hosts:
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/hosts
> ```
>
> You should see what you are looking for fairly quickly, at the top of
>   the file it should look something like: Code:
>
> ```
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
> 127.0.1.1       old_hostname
> ```
>
> Change old_hostname to a new hostname of your choice. Now save and
>   exit.
>
> Second file to edit is /etc/hostname. This does what it says on the
>   tin, the file will have one line in it and that line is your hostname.
>   Change it to your new hostname, save and exit.
>
> Now reboot, you should have a perfectly working system in which sudo
>   works. You can test both sudo and your new hostname by doing, simply:
>
> ```
> sudo hostname
> ```
>
> *NOTE: This command does not usually need to be run sudo, we are just
>   testing both the changed hostname AND sudo at the same time.*
>
> If it doesn't work, see below. You DID take backups, didn't you?
>
> - Get into the grub menu by pressing esc on bootup, or allowing it to display automatically if you have set it up like this
> - Choose recovery mode
> - If prompted, select "drop to single user mode" or similar (note: this applies only on hardy I think)
> - When you are at a root shell, type the following command:
>
>   ```
>   cp /etc/hosts.bak /etc/hosts && cp /etc/hostname.bak /etc/hostname
>   ```
>
> Then press ctrl-alt-del and you should reboot back to a perfectly working system.

Answer (score 4):

Change both `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/hostname
gksudo gedit /etc/hosts
```

Comment: And type `hostname "new name"` so it's taken into consideration without rebooting.

Answer (score 1):

How about `sudo hostname "new computer name"`

Comment: It doesn't last after reboot.