# Change Ubuntu Name

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change computer name of an Ubuntu desktop computer](https://superuser.com/questions/84704/change-computer-name-of-an-ubuntu-desktop-computer)

I have a system and don't like the user sees the Ubuntu name while system is shutting down(i replaced the splash when starting)

I want to know how can i Change my Ubuntu name in console (you can see by pressing ctrl+alt+F1) from UBUNTU to something else.

Comment: This isn't code related. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/84704/change-computer-name-of-an-ubuntu-desktop-computer

Answer (score 1):

- Edit `/etc/hostname` with your editor of choice:

```
sudo vi /etc/hostname
```

save the file with your new hostname.

- You should also edit the hosts file:

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

in there you will see the old hostname which may look something like this:

```
192.168.0.99        oldhostname
```

change it so it looks like this, then save and exit:

```
192.168.0.99        newhostname
```

restart the hostname service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh restart
```

Answer (score 0):

*Copied from the original; migration appears to have bugged out at the precise second I submitted:*

Take a look at the [`hostname`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?hostname) command. You might also need to tweak, e.g. `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the hostname value:

```
hostname "newservername"
```

in the `/etc/hostname` to make it survive reboots.