# Change Ubuntu hostname on the fly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, hostname

First of all, this question is not a duplicate of [Change computer name of an Ubuntu desktop computer](https://superuser.com/questions/84704/change-computer-name-of-an-ubuntu-desktop-computer) or [Change Ubuntu Name](https://superuser.com/questions/90471/change-ubuntu-name/).

I know to change hostname, I need to edit the file `hostname` and `hosts` under `/etc`. No problem with that. The problem is how to change hostname if the system has already booted into the wrong hostname, **without a reboot**. I.e., to change the hostname on the fly.

This was used to be done with `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh`, but now, under my Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy, that file is no longer there. How to change the hostname on the fly then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/bin/hostname` can be used to show *or set* the hostname of a system at run-time.

Comment: that's not what I want becaus it does not change the file `hostname` and `hosts` under `/etc`. It is effective  only  until  the  next  reboot

Comment: `/bin/hostname` is how you change the hostname on the fly.  Altering the configuration file is how you change the hostname at boot-time.